# Can I use IE10, d3.js and moveToFront together? The mouseout event gets lost

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-10

I'm using D3 to draw a line graph that has many crossing lines. I'm also using the "mouseover" event to bring a line into the foreground. Everything works fine on Firefox but not so in IE10 (surprised?). The problem seems to be related to the moveToFront code. Without this code my simple JSFiddle example will work. My actual graph is more complex than then example and I really would like to keep moveToFront in my design. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Check out a simple demo of this problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gCs78/12/

When I run this example in IE10, I can observe multiple "mouseover" events but no "mouseout" events.

Here is the moveToFront code:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() 
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
};
```

Comment: Definitely an IE bug.  See much discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3686132/3128209