# Anomalous mouseover handling with D3.js in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling, internet-explorer-11

I'm developing some svg animations, and I need to detect mouseover/mouseout events in order to change elements' z-index (i.e. elements' order inside svg).
My code works perfectly with Chrome and Firefox, but I ha ve some issues with IE11.
In particular, it seems that, hovering on an element, IE11 detects several mouseover events, and not detecting the following mouseout event.

You can find a dummy example of the issue in https://jsfiddle.net/erdmca23/4/

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var data = d3.range(0, 40); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc]
  console.log('number of items in array: ' + data.length);
  var overcounter = 1;
  var outcounter = 1;

  d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      d3.select('#log').append('div').text('Over counter ' + overcounter++);
      this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
  };

  d3.selection.prototype.moveToBack = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      d3.select('#log').append('div').text('Out counter ' + outcounter++);

      var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild;
      if (firstChild) {
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild);
      }
    });
  };

  var colour = d3.scale.category10();

  // vars
  var rectWidth = 100;
  var rectHeight = 300;

  var svg = d3.select('#container').append('svg');
  // set width & height in css

  svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
      width: rectWidth,
      height: rectHeight,
      x: function(d, i) {
        // overlap the rects intentionally
        return (rectWidth - 40) * i;
      },
      y: 10
    })
    .style({
      fill: function(d, i) {
        return colour(i);
      },
      stroke: 'none'
    })
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).moveToFront();
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).moveToBack();
    })
})();
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Another similar example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/2029/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when you are using d3.selection, it loses mouse events. See this post - [Move active element loses mouseout event in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686132/move-active-element-loses-mouseout-event-in-internet-explorer)

I had to rearrange the way I was appending elements in d3 to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to re-bind the `mouseout` handler to the element once it has been re-appended:

```
...
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .moveToFront()
      .on('mouseout', function(d) { // only bind the mouseout handler here
        d3.select(this).moveToBack();
      })
    })
...
```

Full jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb304wth/). Note that to test it you're going to need to go to [jsfiddle.net/fiddle/show](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb304wth/show), since JSfiddle won't load on IE.

The culprit is `this.parentNode.appendChild(this)`, as stated by [Kate O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7154598/kate-o)'s [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686132/move-active-element-loses-mouseout-event-in-internet-explorer). Re-appending the element breaks IE's association between the re-appended element and state of whether the mouse has entered that element. Re-binding the callback simulates that enter-exit state.

for d3 v4+ users, this problem applies to [d3.selection.raise()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_raise) or [.lower()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_lower), both of which re-insert the selected element into the DOM.