# R Leaflet labels and highlights do not disappear in IE

Tags: r, internet-explorer, browser, leaflet

I have been making a leaflet map in R and I would like to turn highlighting and labeling on however when the map is displayed in Internet Explorer if you move the mouse too quickly the highlighting or labels will not always disappear when the mouse leaves a shape.  It works fine in Chrome.  I was hoping someone might know how to apply a fix.

I have searched SO and Github and not seen any documentation of this issue, but I may have missed something. I also scanned through the underlining java script, but my java skill are not up to the task of solving this one.

Here is a minimum example:

```
# From https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html
states <- readOGR("cb_2016_us_state_500k.shp",
                  layer = "cb_2016_us_state_500k", GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE)

leaflet(states) %>%
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "blue", weight = 7,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE))
```

In internet explorer this produces:

[image]

Comment: Using windows 10. I don't get this problem using Internet Explorer 11.1198. But I do get it using Edge.

Comment: I encountered the problem in IE 10 and Edge.  I did not test other browsers.

Comment: This may well be due to a mouseout event being lost, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686132/move-active-element-loses-mouseout-event-in-internet-explorer In which case, any solution would need to start tinkering with the leaflet javascript.

Comment: FYI - I noticed that this problem does not​ appear to effect other maps generated using leaflet js. Just those generated in R.

Comment: Can you post this to the web somewhere (rpubs for example) so we can get our hands on the actual javascript and try to suss this out?

Comment: Here it is on rpubs: http://rpubs.com/IanWesley/277899

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it seems to work fine when you set `bringToFront = FALSE`. Hence, one solution is to only increase stroke width and not change color, then bringToFront is not needed. Obviously, this will likely not solve any issue with labels but it does seem to solve the problem of the highlighting not disappearing in the provided example.

Comment: I think this approach is worth developing. I have tried it in edge using `addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5, label = "Label",
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "blue", weight = 7,
                                                  bringToFront = FALSE))` The labels and highlights both disappear. The stroke doesn't come to the front, which is a minor frustration, but may be acceptable.